# Deleting the 'svn' file inside Working Copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out a repository into a folder on my Desktop, called `MyWorkingCopy`.

I never noticed any extra files (to do with svn operations) in the folder, until I had to resolve a conflict, after which I noticed a little `svn` file had been created.

I inadvertently deleted this file, and so the overlay icon disappeared. I believe my working copy folder is now dissociated from the repository. Right?

How do I now commit my changes to the repository?  Can I continue to work with `MyWorkingCopy` as usual, and then commit when I am done, or would that cause a deluge of conflicts?

I am asking first to find out what's the best course of action, rather than try to commit first and see what happens...

So, I would appreciate insightful comments to help me understand this issue in depth.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer have a working copy. You only have a bunch of files.

The simplest fix is probably to check out a new working copy *somewhere else* and then drop your modified files there with Windows explorer. Ask "overwrite" when prompted and you should be able to commit your changes.

If you've deleted and/or renamed files, you could use a regular file comparison tool (instead of just dropping files), but you should ensure you've recorded renames properly before you commit. TortoiseSVN has a fancy [repair moves/renames](http://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html) feature.

Answer (score 0):

As your WorkingCopy isn't connected with the repo anymore I think you will not be able to commit it. Just check it out a second time. Make sure there are no other changes than yours and replace your changed files with the one in the new Repo. when trying to commit make sure there are no conflicts by checking all modified files.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this document helps  http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/learning-subversion-the-mystery-of-svn-2/

" The svn folders created are actually administrative directories. 
The files in each administrative directory help Subversion recognize which files contain unpublished changes, and which files are out of date with respect to others’ work."

Read after -  "unversioned” files vs. files “under version control”

Answer (score 0):

You can use **svn import** to add your file to the repository.